# Responsive Video sections all having 100vh and 100vw without using position:fixed

Tags: html, css, background

I want to create a one page website with multiple sections. Each section containing a video having height and width equal to the viewport size (100vh and 100vw), these videos stack on top on one another(each taking full width and full height of the browser view port).

I saw few tutorials online where they explain to use position fixed for responsive purposes. 
However in other sections i do not want the video as a background. Is there a way to make it happen ?
(position absolute is not an option as when i resize it doesn't take full width and full height of the page even when playing with @media).

I simply want these responsive video sections so that they do not break or overflow when browser is re-sized.

**Edit :**

here is my code html

```html
<section class="section1">
     <video id="videoBG" autoplay muted loop>
      <source src="style/vid/1_first.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     </video>
</section>


<section class="section2">
 <video id="videoBG2" autoplay muted loop>
      <source src="style/vid/2_second.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     </video> 
</section>
```

and the css :

```css
section {
 height: 100vh;
}

.section1 #videoBG, .section2 #videoBG2 {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: -1;
}


/* Make video responsive for every size resizing*/

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) AND (min-aspect-ratio: 8/5) AND (min-aspect-ratio: 4/3) AND (min-aspect-ratio: 3/2){
 .section1 #videoBG, .section2 #videoBG2{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) AND (max-aspect-ratio: 8/5) AND (max-aspect-ratio: 4/3) AND (max-aspect-ratio: 3/2) {
    .section1 #videoBG, .section2 #videoBG2 { 
        width:auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Imran, However it did not seem to do the trick for me as the video still extand to the right more than the width viewport when i resize

Comment: Could you share your code on jsfiddle so that I can see what you want to acheive.

Comment: Let me look into it and debug it.

Comment: Thanks man you're great :D

Comment: I am just a simple human, dust. God Almighty is indeed great. By the way I just need to know why are we using section 2 and what do you want to achieve with video 2. Just clarify

Comment: So basically i want a few section of full height of viewport each. Each section has a video but if i use position fixed, only the first video is showing everywhere and if i use absolute then the video goes a bit crazy with the size whenevere i resize my browser. i also tried the other positions but the result is not satisfying :/

Comment: So you basically want a stack of videos one after the other and each taking 100vh, so that first you see first video on full screen. Then when you scroll down, you see second video and so on. Is this what you want to achieve friend :)

Comment: it's exactly that :)

Comment: Sure, I am creating one project for you, once done. I will share the code. Don't worry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212483/discussion-between-imran-rafiq-rather-and-mathi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the question is concerned. You need to stack videos on top of one another. And all video sections should have 100vh.

The idea is to surround our video sections in a wrapper container (`<main id="videosWrapper"><main>`).

If we use `object-fit:cover`, the problem is solved.

```
#videosWrapper{
 max-width:100vw;
 max-height:100vh;
}
```

And then for the individual videos, use the following CSS:

```
.videoCSS{
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

**CHECK THE FULL CODE BELOW:**

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#videosWrapper{
  max-width:100vw;
  max-height:100vh;
}

.videoCSS{
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Stack of full screen videos</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <main id="videosWrapper">
    <section class="section1">
      <video class="videoCSS" autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4"
          type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </section>


    <section class="section2">
      <video class="videoCSS" autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerMeltdowns.mp4"
          type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </section>

    <section class="section2">
      <video class="videoCSS" autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4"
          type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </section>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

**Note:** `object-fit:cover` does not work on IE/Edge.